# Google App Engine: AJAX without using RPC (Java)

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine

I am new to GAE & AJAX and have been trying to learn GAE by writing a few apps using JAVA (without GWT though). Could someone please tell me if it's possible to write AJAX application without using Python or RPC with Java? If yes, any sample?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write a good app using JavaScript (or a library like jQuery) and regular HTTP requests.

There are many examples available online. Like this one:
http://vimeo.com/m/8066901

Answer (score 1):

code on GAE runs on the server, where as AJAX code is done in the browser, most typical is JavaScript.

You can have a Java class that extends HttpServlet and have that run on GAE and then have a java script call it and send POST or GET parameters to it and receive a response and do what is needed.  This is called a servlet, you can google it or get many books on the subject.

```
public class Biller extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        //Do something in here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually GEA app is very similar to a Java EE web app. You can just app JSP files and do anything you want inside JSP. And even more you can add static HTML files. Just put them to /web directory and they will be available in the root of the website after the deployment.